Properties of an ODE solution on $\mathbb{R}$.
Let $y$ be a solution of the ODE $y'=arctan(y)$ and y(0)>0. Show that y is a monotone increasing function.
My attempt:
First we notice, that the arctan function on $\mathbb{R}$ has the following properties:

$arctan(x)=0 \iff x=0 $, $arctan(x)<0 \iff x<0 $ and $arctan(x)>0 \iff x>0 $.

This implies that for our ODE it holds, that

$y'(x)=0 \iff y(x)=0 $, $y'(x)<0 \iff y(x)<0 $ and $y'(x)>0 \iff y(x)>0 $.

Let $y$ be a solution and $y(0)> 0$. I now want to show that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}:y(x)\geq 0$ which implies $y'(x)\geq0$ and therefore the solution is monotone increasing.
Suppose for contradiction, that there exists a point $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $y(x_0) < 0$.
First we assume, that $x_0<0$.By our observations above we know that $y'(x_0) < 0$. By the definition of differentiability, we know that for an $\epsilon >0$ it holds that $\forall x \in (x_0,x_0+\epsilon): y(x)<y(x_0)$.
So we find a point $x_1 \in (x_0,x_0+\epsilon): y(x_1)<y(x_0)$. As $y(0) > 0$, the intermediate value theorem tells us, that there has to exist a point $x_2 \in (x_1,0)$ such that $y(x_2)=y(x_0)$ and we choose $x_2$ to be the first point with this property that is greater than $x_1$.
So now we have the case that $\forall x \in (x_0,x_2): y(x)<y(x_0)$ . According to Rolle's Theorem there has to exist a point $x_3 \in (x_0,x_2): y'(x_3)=0$ as $y(x_2)=y(x_0)$. So we found a point $x_3\in \mathbb{R}: y(x_3)<0$ and $y'(x_3)=0$, which is a contradiction.
If $x_0>0$ the proof is pretty much the same.
I would like to know your thoughts on my proof and maybe if there is a more clever way. Thanks in advance to everyone. :)

Are you allowed to use the mean value theorem?

@Wei for sure! This was just a subpoint of a series of questions and I used it in the other subpoints.

@Wei I think i can already see what u are hinting, just use the fact that we would find a root closest to the point x0 and use mean value theorem with the point x0 and the root which also would lead to a point with either positive function value and negative gradient  or a point with negative function value and positive gradient.

Your proof works. Here's an alternative.
Assume there exists $x<0$ with $y(x) <0 $, then by intermediate value theorem there is $x_1\in (x,0)$ with $y(x_1)=0$. Take the smallest such $x_1$, then by mean value theorem there is $x_2\in(x,x_1)$ with $y'(x_2)>0$ but $y(x_2)<0$, a contradiction.
Now assume there exists $x>0$ with $y(x) <0 $, then by intermediate value theorem there is $x_1\in (0,x)$ with $y(x_1)=0$. Take the smallest such $x_1$, then by mean value theorem there is $x_2\in(0,x_1)$ with $y'(x_2)<0$ but $y(x_2)>0$, a contradiction.
So $y\geq0$ everywhere, so $y'\geq0$ everywhere, so $y$ monotonic increasing.

Thanks that’s exactly what i thought of once you mentioned the mean value theorem in your comment above.:)

If there is a point $x_0$ such that $y’(x_0)=0$, then it implies $y(x_0)=0$. On the other hand, the constant zero function solves the ODE (and this initial condition), so by uniqueness of solutions (which we definitely have given how nice $\arctan$ is) it follows that $y\equiv 0$. This contradicts the fact that $y(0)>0$.
Hence, we have shown that $y’$ is nowhere-vanishing. By Darboux’s intermediate value theorem for derivatives (or simply the usual intermediate value theorem for continuous functions applied to $y’$, since $y$ is actually $C^{\infty}$ by the ODE), it follows $y’$ maintains the same sign everywhere, and this sign is positive since $y’(0)=\arctan(y(0))>0$. Hence $y$ is strictly increasing.
